# Use multiple IF in scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a scalar function below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[lengthCheck] 
(@string nvarchar(14))
RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@string) < 8
        BEGIN
            return 1
        END
    IF LEN(@string) > 14
        BEGIN
            return 2
        END
    return 0    
END
```

If my input length is less than 8 then need to return 1, if greater then 14 then return 2 else return 0

Below is the output:

```
select [dbo].[lengthCheck] ('123')  --> return 1 

select [dbo].[lengthCheck] ('123456789') --> return 0
```

but when I input more then 14 characters then it is not returning 2

```
select [dbo].[lengthCheck] ('1234567899999999') --> return still as 0
```

Expected output:

```
select [dbo].[lengthCheck] ('1234567899999999') --> return 2
```

Comment: Asides: `RETURNS nvarchar(50)` and `return 2` make a somewhat odd pair. From [`Len()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you've defined the input parameter as `nvarchar(14)`, so you can never pass more than 14 characters in. So redefine that to the actual maximum length you want to support e.g. `nvarchar(max)`

Then use a `case` expression as its more suited to this kind of logic.

```
RETURN CASE WHEN LEN(@string) < 8 THEN 1 WHEN LEN(@string) > 14 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

The input is `nvarchar(14)` so it will always be 14 characters. When the `nvarchar` size is increased it will return as 2 for `LEN(@string) > 14`.

Comment: yes i just noticed..will mark your answer as correct.thanks